# Itext7 - pdfHTML - Document SetMargins method is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, itext7

I'm working on `Itext7` and I'm into trouble `Documen`t cannot set `Width/Height`, `Margin` on this one.
I have researched (via stack overflow, `itext7_pdfHTML` ebook and so for) but have not found out the solution.

```
    public static byte[] GeneratePdf(string rootPath, string htmlString)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(stream))
            {
                using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
                {
                    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                    pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    var document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmlString, pdfDocument, GetConverterProperties(rootPath));
                    document.SetMargins(1,2,3,4);
                    document.Close();

                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Would it be possible for anyone to tell me what I'm missing?

I have some following questions:

1. The object order (I mean MemoryStream -> PdfWriter -> pdfDocument) is correct, isn't it?
2. I was wondering stream has been not affected after generating document?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.SetMargins` changes the margins for upcoming pages, not for already generated ones. I'm not sure what the best solution is but using `@media print` definitions would be an option.

Comment: tks for your response, I'll check it. 
btw, I didn't know why my font has been included but not font bold.
Furthermore, my CSS doesn't work as I expected (I've used ItextSharp (aka itext5 before and this one work fine for me)).

Comment: If iText 5 processed your HTML&CSS better, you might want to make that a dedicated question.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really deep into the html-to-pdf stuff, so I have no immediate idea. I've marked the question, though. If I find some time to spare, I may investigate that.

Comment: Hi @mkl, Could you pls give me the answer then I can mark it as resolved? I really appreciate your help. Thanks, sir.

Comment: I did not dive into the details of the html-to-pdf stuff, so I can essentially only make an answer from my comment. Is that ok?

Comment: Yeah, That makes sense. sir :) @mkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.SetMargins` changes the margins for upcoming pages, not for already generated ones. This explains why your setting the margins after the `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument` call does not influence the result of the conversion.

You might instead try to use `@media print` definitions in the HTML source or the `MediaDeviceDescription` object in the `ConverterProperties` you supply to `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument`.

Alternatively you may use `HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements` instead of `HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument` and add the returned elements to a `Document` you created with page size and margin settings of your choice.

Which approach is best, depends on details of your task, e.g. on whether you can easily influence the `@media print` definitions in the HTML source.

Concerning your other question

> The object order (I mean MemoryStream -> PdfWriter -> pdfDocument) is correct, isn't it?

Yes, it is. Strictly speaking, though, you should move the retrieval of the `byte[]` down a bit to something like this:

```c#
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
    {
        [...]
    }
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

In your code it can remain in your innermost `using` because you call it after `document.Close()` which calls `pdfDocument.Close` which in turn calls `pdfWriter.Close`; if in other code you don't close things explicitly and count on `using` doing that for you, though, that `byte[]` retrieval needs to move out.